# Large SmartGWT ListGrid in TabPanel, how to get one set of scroll bars

Tags: scroll, smartgwt, tabpanel, listgrid

I have a potentially very large ListGrid that is one panel of a GWT TabPanel.  Even giving it a width of 2000 pixels and a height of 6000 pixels, it does not fit in either dimension.  Which means I end up with a vertical scroll bar for the TabPanel (the screen isn't 6000 px high) and horizontal and vertical scrollbars for the ListGrid.

So users will have very few items in this ListGrid, while others will have hundreds of lines.  Is there a way to tell the ListGrid to just fit the size of the enclosing panel, and only have one set of scrollbars?

Thank you,
Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the answer:

```
theGrid.setAutoFitData (Autofit.VERTICAL);
theGrid.setHeight (1);
theGrid.setShowAllRecords (true);
theGrid.setBodyOverflow (Overflow.VISIBLE);
theGrid.setOverflow (Overflow.VISIBLE);
theGrid.setLeaveScrollbarGap (false);
```

This sets up the ListGrid so that it changes size based on the number of rows it has, and does not restrict its size to the viewable area.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling [setWidth100()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/Canvas.html#setWidth100%28%29) and [setHeight100()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/Canvas.html#setHeight100%28%29)?

```
listGrid.setWidth100();
listGrid.setHeight100();
```

Calling these methods is the SmartGWT equivalent of setting the width and height to "100%".

Comment: Yes, I've tried that.  But no matter what I do to the size of the window, the ListGrid is always just a bit bigger than it, and I end up with two vertical scrollbars and one horizontal one

Comment: @GregDougherty: I just realized that your `ListGrid` is within a GWT `TabPanel` instead of a SmartGWT `TabSet`. I am pretty sure that percent dimensions only work like what you are expecting when the grid is within a SmartGWT `Layout`. Although you can set GWT widget dimensions to percents, this is not like SmartGWT, which has a much more sophisticated layout system. Try using a SmartGWT `TabSet`. That should solve your problem.